# ruby on rails sending email with multi-line body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm sending email using Ruby on Rails

```
subject = "test"
line1 = "first line"
line2 = "second line"
body = line1 + "\n" + line2
mail(to: ['myaddress@gmail.com'], subject: subject, body: body).deliver
```

I want the email body be presented in multi-lines so I used "\n". But I got only one line combining line1 and line2. Anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: try  `"#{body = line1 + "\n" + line2}".html_safe`, but I'm not sure it'll work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amit Suroliya answer is correct but for this operation you should use `.html.erb` template format for email and you definitely should use `.html_safe` for body. If you use `.text.erb` format for email it just show you plain text

Comment: I'm using haml to create a template here.

Comment: Yes, but for actually email you need to use .html.erb template format

Comment: You don't know where his line1 and line2 are coming from.  You should not be advising him to use html_safe on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not specified if you are sending as HTML or text, or both; I'll just assume both.

Also, I'm not sure why you need to concatenate the lines before they reach your email template.

Typically in your mailer you can just use instance variables and access them in your templates which automatically composes the body.

Mailer:

```
@line1 = "first line"
@line2 = "second line"
mail(to: ['myaddress@gmail.com'], subject: subject).deliver
```

Mailer HTML ERB Template:

```
<%= @line1 %>
<br/>
<%= @line2 %>
```

**HTML Emails**

To get new lines in HTML emails you need each line wrapped in a paragraph tag (<p>, </p>) or by using line break(<br/>) tags between lines.

Rails has a safe and convenient function ([simple_format](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format)) to do this for you.

HTML ERB Template:

```
<%= simple_format(@some_multiline_text) %>
```

**Text Emails**

According to [RFC 2282](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) line breaks in text emails are delimited by CRLF (Ruby's default is LF - "\n").  You can simply find and replace LF with CRLF using gsub.

Text ERB Template:

```
<%= @some_multiline_text.gsub('\n', '\r\n')
<%= "\r\n" %>
Above is a line break.
```

**Sanitize brefore html_safe**

To quote an [excellent article](https://www.sitepoint.com/common-rails-security-pitfalls-and-their-solutions/) on avoiding common rails security pitfalls:

> Therefore, if you display user-generated content on a page, never
>   apply the html_safe method directly to it. First, use the sanitize
>   method and specify the list of permitted tags: usually the ones used
>   for formatting, like b or i:

Based on your example.

```
subject = "test"
line1 = "first line"
line2 = "second line"
body = sanitize(line1 + "\n" + line2, tags: %w(b strong em i)).html_safe
mail(to: ['myaddress@gmail.com'], subject: subject, body: body).deliver
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this -

```
  body = "#{line1} <br> #{line2}"
  mail(to: ['myaddress@gmail.com'], subject: subject, body: body.html_safe).deliver
```

Comment: I guess I must render a html to make this happen.

Comment: Don't just throw html_safe around, it can be a security risk if you are dealing with rendering user input.